# how to count how many times a video was clicked in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have videos on my Laravel project and I want to be able to count how many times a video was clicked. I haven't found no legit tutorial on this. I have a feeling that this is not complicated to do.Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a few ways you can do it. Either Ajax a request to your controller when someone starts a video, or update the database anytime someone clicks on the route to go to the video.

Comment: @Mahurin I will want to do update the database anytime they click it. But the thing about it is that when you click the video that’s when it plays. I don’t know if I have to prevent the default using JS

Comment: I would just add a div around the video container. Add an onclick event listener on the div, so when the click on the video container the onclick event for that div will trigger, which you can use to send the ajax.

Comment: @N Mahurin ok I will try to do that. Thank you